Problema al mostrar en Google Collab un DataFrame tengo 3 columnas
Tengo un csv de 3 columnas al mostrarlos en un DataFrame en Google Colab me sale la 3ª columna debajo. Mi archivo csv está delimitado por ",", la tercerca columa deberia salirme al costado.


Si dices que esta delimitado por una coma, esto podría servir.
data = pd.read_csv('datasets.csv', sep=',')

Aunque si ya le estas pasando este parámetro podridas enviar como lo estas cargando el archivo.

Que se muestre así el DataFrame no quiere decir que se esté parseando mal el csv o que la estructura del DataFrame este mal, es solo un "problema" a la hora de mostrarlo / imprimirlo.
En este caso la causa es que tu DataFrame necesita un ancho de linea relativamente grande para mostrase al completo por lo que pandas realiza un ajuste del texto (wrap) y muestra la tercera columna debajo.
Por otro lado, te recomiendo mostrar los DataFrames en Jupyter/ipython usando display() en vez de print(), te lo mostrará en una bonita tabla HTML, generalmente mas legible y atractiva visualmente. Puedes usar display implícitamente o explícitamente:

Dicho esto, para evitar que al usar print te imprima la columna debajo puedes simplemente hacer uso de la opción de configuración display.width (80 caracteres por defecto), bien temporalmente mediante administrador de contexto:
with pd.option_context('display.width', 1000):
    print(df)

o bien de forma general mediante pandas.set_option():
pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)

Si también quieres que no corte el contenido de las celdas demasiado largas puedes ajustar también display.max_colwidth:
with pd.option_context('display.width', 1000, 'display.max_colwidth', None):
    print(df)


Tienes muchas mas opciones disponibles que puedes configurar para ajustar otras cosas, como el máximo de filas a imprimir o el número de decimales de los floats a mostrar:

Pandas User Guide. Options and settings - Setting startup options in Python/IPython environment


Gracias me fue muy util la información brindada
